# How can I use 'toString()' as source in org.mapstruct.Mapping?

Tags: java, mapping, mapstruct

I want to use `Foo::toString` as source in `@org.mapstruct.Mapping`

Solutions below doesn't work:

```
@Mapping(source = "value.toString()", target = "date")
String map(Foo value);
```

> java: The type of parameter "value" has no property named "toString()".

```
@Mapping(source = "java(value.toString())", target = "date")
String map(Foo value);
```

> java: No property named "java(value.toString())" exists in source parameter(s).

---

- I cannot change `Foo` class (no `Lombok` insite)
- Mapper configuration: `@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")`.
- Any advice?

---

Let's define Foo as:

```
public class Foo {
    private final int x;
    public Foo(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "" + this.x;
    }
}
```

using:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

...

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>1.4.2.Final</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 3):

looks like this solution is working:

```
@Mapping(expression = "java(value.toString())", target = "foo")
```

but on different level (on parent object which contains field with type `Foo` )
like:

```
public class Bar {
    Foo foo;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

MapStruct does not support generating mapping methods for Object to String like that.

What you can do is to write your own custom method.

e.g.

```
default String map(Foo value) {
    return value != null ? value.toString() : null;
}
```